# How can I breakdown different segment of the graph

Tags: plotting

I have constructed a graph using `ListLinePlot`, using the existing input data from the matrix calculation.

May I ask how can I create a different segment based on existing graph. 
The graph x-axis ranges from 0 to 540. I need to create three segments, based on the existing graph that I have.

[image]

So between 0 to 540, I need help in creating three segments from the existing data to 0-220, 221-421, 422 to 540.  I have tried using `DataRange`, but the outcomes are still the same.

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what do you want to achieve. Please show some exemplary dataset, the plot, and describe in more detail what's the output you want to obtain.

Comment: Thanks corey979, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
lst1 = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 540]];
```

**1. Restructure your input data:**

```
lst2 = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, lst1];

{data1, data2, data3} = {lst2[[;; 220]], lst2[[221 ;; 421]], lst2[[422 ;;]]};

ListLinePlot[{data1, data2, data3} ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**2. Use `Mesh` and `MeshShading`:**

```
ListLinePlot[lst1, Mesh -> {{221, 422}}, MeshShading -> {Red, Blue, Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**3. Use `ColorFunction` that specifies different colors for different values of `x`:**

```
ListLinePlot[lst1, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction->Function[{x, y}, Which[x <= 220, Orange, 221 <= x < 421, Cyan, True, Red]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**4. Plot each piece separately with appropriate `DataRange` values and combine with `Show`:**

```
ranges = {{1, 220}, {221, 421}, {422, 540}};
colors = {Red,  Green, Purple};

plots = ListLinePlot[lst1[[Span @@ #]],  DataRange -> #, 
     PlotStyle -> #2] & @@@ Transpose[{ranges, colors}];
Show[plots, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**5. Post-process `ListLinePlot` output to add different directives for different pieces:**

```
ListLinePlot[lst1] /. 
 Line[x_] :> ({#, Line[x[[Span @@ #2]]]} & @@@ Transpose[{colors, ranges}])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks Kglr! It was really useful! I will give a try. Appreciate it!